# How to create a filter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Using AngularJS, how do you create a subset of items in an array?

For example; create a new array from "todos" that only includes the  "done:true" items.

```
function fooController ($scope) {

$scope.todos = [
        {text:'foo'        , done:false}, 
        {text:'foobar'     , done:true},
        {text:'foofoo'     , done:false}, 
        {text:'foobar2'    , done:true}
 ]

}
```

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4&list=PL173F1A311439C05D&context=C48ac877ADvjVQa1PpcFONnl4Q5x8hqvT6tRBTE-m0-Ym47jO3PEE%3D](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4&list=PL173F1A311439C05D&context=C48ac877ADvjVQa1PpcFONnl4Q5x8hqvT6tRBTE-m0-Ym47jO3PEE=)

See about 10:45 -> end

Comment: ok, i create a sample in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394055/checkbox-list-breaks-why-and-optimal-angularjs-way/16395257#16395257.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the filter to your ngRepeat and only show what you want:

```
ng-repeat='todo in todos | filter:done==true'
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dPWsv/1/

If you want to completely REMOVE the element from the list, utilize the `archive` function in the fiddle.

**Note**: as of version 1.1.3 the filter behavior has changed. You'll now want to use

```
ng-repeat='todo in todos | filter:{done:true}'
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdbVL/1/

Comment: I eventually got this working. Thanks for the assistance.  https://github.com/spudstud/angular-todo

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

update variable with only data checked

your model :

```
$scope.todos = [
        {text:'foo'        , done:false}, 
        {text:'foobar'     , done:true},
        {text:'foofoo'     , done:false}, 
        {text:'foobar2'    , done:true}
 ]
```

you want only checked :

```
$scope.todoselect = $filter('filter')($scope.todos, {done:true});
```

when model change you want to update your variable so use watch in controller

```
$scope.$watch('todos', function(newval, oldval){
                        if (oldval != newval)
                        {   
                      $scope.todoselect = $filter('filter')($scope.todos, {done: true});
                            }
                            },true
                        );
  });
```

Sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/PnABre?p=preview